# Malformed URL: '', skipping (java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

i crawl sites with nutch 1.3. i see this exception in my log when nutch crawl my sites:

```
Malformed URL: '', skipping (java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator$Selector.reduce(Generator.java:247)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator$Selector.reduce(Generator.java:109)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
```

)

how can i solve this? help me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs.
"MalformedURLException is thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed."

The thing to be noted here is that this exception is not thrown when the server is down or when the path points to a missing file. It occurs only when URL cannot be parsed.

The error indicates that there is *no protocol*. and also the crawler does not see any URL,

Malformed URL: **''** , skipping (java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Here is interesting article that I came across, have a look http://www.symphonious.net/2007/03/29/javaneturl-or-javaneturi/

What is the exact URL you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

After having set all setting with `regex-urlfilter.txt` and `seed.txt` try this command:

```
./nutch plugin protocol-file org.apache.nutch.protocol.file.File file:\\\e:\\test.html
```

(if the file is located at `e:\test.htm` in my example.

Before this, I always ran this

```
./nutch plugin protocol-file org.apache.nutch.protocol.file.File \\\e:\test.html
```

and got this error, because the protocol `file:` was missing:

> java.netMalformedURLException : no protocol : \\e:\test.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Malformed URL: ''
```

means that the URL was empty instead of being something like http://www.google.com.